# Uninstall fake-hwclock leaves files behind

Tags: battery, ubuntu-14.04

My machine arrived without a CMOS battery so I installed fake-hwclock to attempt to at least have reasonable and increasing times.  I've installed the CMOS battery and attempted to remove fake-hwclock but am still having problems.  The RTC appears to work as shown by

```
 dmesg | grep rtc
 [    0.619589] rtc_cmos 00:06: RTC can wake from S4
 [    0.620641] rtc_cmos 00:06: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
 [    0.621476] rtc_cmos 00:06: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
 [    0.649771] rtc_cmos 00:06: setting system clock to 2014-12-17 18:09:34 UTC (1418839774)
```

I checked the /etc/rc*.d files and found links to fake-hwclock in /etc/init.d

Is it safe for me to delete the links and script?

Comment: You flagged this "Ubuntu" - uninstalling fake-hwclock should not leave files behind in /etc. If it does, maybe you edited those files?  If not, you could file a [bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fake-hwclock/+bugs)

Comment: I discovered the files after I discovered in some log that they were still there after my attempted removal.  I installed and removed them again with no change. Since the system doesn't appear to work any worse after I changee the script name I guess it is save to remove them by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the links, script, and data file caused no problems following an attempt to remove fake-hwclock. I'll look into filing a bug report as suggested by ckajau.